# Get data from an external XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am using this code so far but its not working for me:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Mumbai';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$lat=$xml->lat;
echo "Latitude:".$lat;
echo '<br/>';
$lng=$xml->lng;
echo "Longitude:".$lng;
echo '<br/>';
?>
```

I tried other questions as well in this site but didn't got any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please define "not working"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Lix I mean to say, I am not getting the latitude and longitude value from that XML file

Comment: Yes - but where exactly are you having problems? Are you able to retrieve the file? Can you see it's contents at all?

Comment: @Lix I think I am able to retrieve the file but not the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml->result->geometry->location->lat
```